# Formatting Datasource of Dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, drop-down-menu

I’m trying to configure a data source for a dropdown list. 
The database table have fields’ `(id, value, parenttypeid)`
The parent typeid can be 0 or 1,2..etc,
I want to populate the dropdown list according to parent and child
can be shown like -:>

```
Parent1
    Child1
    Child2
Parent 2
```

I tried this by ordering the result but could not get the format. 
If anyone got idea please reply
Thanks

Comment: How about recursion iteration through items ?

Comment: Also, it's a pretty good idea to include some code when asking questions. It's a lot easier to help you if you do.

Comment: You have received good answers for your questions, but haven't accepted even one. It's *give* and take, dude. Stop asking people for help if you're unwilling to take 2 seconds and accept the answer.

Comment: There's an outline of a check mark to the left of each answer. Click it.

Comment: @kasun Something wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    class Node
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Node> Child { get; private set; }

        public Node(string name)
        {
            Child = new List<Node>();
            Name = name;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var listItems = new List<string>();
        var root = new Node("Root");
        root.Child.Add(new Node("1"));
        root.Child.Add(new Node("3"));
        var node = new Node("4");
        var nd = new Node("5");
        nd.Child.Add(new Node("7"));
        node.Child.Add(nd);
        node.Child.Add(new Node("6"));
        root.Child.Add(node);

        GetNames(root, listItems);

        foreach (var listItem in listItems)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(listItem);
        }
    }

    static void GetNames(Node parent, List<string> result)
    {
        result.Add(parent.Name);
        foreach (var child in parent.Child)
        {
            GetNames(child, result);
        }
    }
```

[image: screen]

Answer (score 1):

I think you would solve it by first sorting on `Value` and the by `parentTypeId`.

Although it would help if you posted some code, if you want help.

Bu I guess it could look something like this:

```
var myList = myThings
   .OrderBy(t => t.Value)
   .ThenBy(t.ParentTypeId)
   .Select(t => new {
       Text = t.Value,
       Value = t.Id 
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

What about adding `string` in front to the child elements

```
if(parent)
   return element;
else
  return " - "+ element;
```